# Is it possible to get the filtered rows of an Ag Grid in dash-ag-grid?

Tags: python, ag-grid, plotly-dash

In a callback I'd like to get the rows displayed in the AgGrid after all of the native filters are applied.

Currently, if I apply some filters and get the data:
State("ag_grid_table", "rowData")

I get the entire data.
In a dash DataTable I'd use:

```
State("derived_virtual_data", "data")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation

> virtualRowData (list of dicts; optional): The rowData in the grid after inline filters are applied.
>
> rowData (list of dicts; optional): (Client-Side Row Model only) Set the data to be displayed as rows in the grid.

https://dash.plotly.com/dash-ag-grid/reference

So to get the entire data set you'd use `rowData` and to get the filtered rows you'd use `virtualRowData`.

Comment: Ah that's perfect  for some reason I hadn't come across the documentation on the dash-plotly website, just the AgGrid website!